# Eclipse Juno: Missing the "Classic Update"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

In my project we control the plug-ins through the "Manage Configuration" possibility.
Downloaded plu-ins etc. are loaded thorugh an extension point from a file location (managed by SVN)

This has proven to be a reliable way of making sure all developers in a team share the same configuration.

I am now updating our project to Juno, and even after enabling the "Classic Update" in preferences, the menu item Help->Software Update->Manage Configuration is missing.

It also seems to be missing in the documentation for juno at http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Update Manager was deprecated a while ago, and has finally been removed in Juno (4.2).  You can use the [p2 director](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html&cp=2_0_20_2) to perform command-line based installs.

There are other command line apps that can assist with mirroring features in existing update sites to a local directory that can be shared within a company or creating a composite repo that points off to multiple separate update sites (kinda one-stop-shopping) and even publishers that can take featuers and plugins without metadata and prep them for use with the p2 director.

EDIT: A quick tour of options is available here: http://pweclipse.blogspot.ca/2011/06/p2-cheatsheet.html